# Do not use -ObjC flag for linked library in XCode

Tags: objective-c, cordova

I need to link two libraries in a project, Cordova and a library from a hardware manufacturer. The hardware manufacturer's library gives an error if you compile with `-ObjC` but Cordova requires `-ObjC` flag.

Is there a way to force the `-ObjC` flag for a library and not for the other (or vice-versa)?

Thanks!

> Specific error: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMusicPlayerController", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libdtdev.a(AudioStream.o)

Comment: Did you ever figure out why this happened? I'm hitting the same issue, but I don't feel like adding the MediaPlayer framework is a "solution".

Comment: In this case the Cordova framework needed the dependent library, in this case Media player.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a posted the question just before I figured it out (like always). Instead of deleting the post, someone might want to know what the solution was...

If I keep the -ObjC flag in place and add the frameworks it's complaining about to the "Link Binary With Libraries" section (in my case "MediaPlayer.framework").